# What hardware do I really need for a headless server VM in virt-manager that I'll only ever SSH to?

Tags: debian, kvm, virt-manager

I am creating a new VM in virt-manager. I am looking at some of the default HW added and am wondering if all are really needed?

- Tablet
- Display Spice
- Console 1
- Channel (qemu-ga)
- Channel (spice)
- Video Virtio
- Controller USB
- Controller PCIe
- USB Redirector 1
- USB Redirector 2

[image]